# Regex to match decimal number

Tags: php, regex, decimal, preg-match

I am using PHP and wish to use preg_match to give a TRUE/FALSE based on the below.

2 numbers up to a max of 23 on the left of the decimal then 2 numbers up to a max of 59 to the right of the decimal. The numbers do not need to be the same on either side of the decimal. The below conditions should return as follows.

.y = true

.yy = true

x = true

xx = true

xxx = false

x.y = true

xx.y = true

x.yy = true

xx.yy = true

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why can't you just check your input number using an inequality?

Comment: Would this be a better option ? What would the benefits be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
^(2[0-3]|1?[0-9])?(\.[0-5]?[0-9])?$
```

See a demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/acn11r/1).